# asp mvc roles from httpcontext

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

i want to pass current area name to authorization attribute, like:

```
[SexyAuthorize(Roles = Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["area"])]
public class FormsController : Controller
{
}
```

but Url is member of controller. how can i pass it other way?

i know that i can use User.InRole in each method, but i want do it for class. thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass dynamic values to an attribute like this. All values passed to an attribute in .NET need to be known at compile time. One possible workaround is to fetch this value in your custom implementation of the attribute as you have access to the HTTP context.

Something like:

```
[SexyAuthorize(RolesRouteParamName = "area")]
public class FormsController : Controller
{
    ...
}
```

and then:

```
public SexyAuthorizeAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public string RolesRouteParamName { get; set; }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
        }
        var roles = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Value[RolesRouteParamName];
        // TODO: continue with the implementation...
        ...
    }
}
```